# Get filename as a request parameter

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I try to load a file with node.js.

In my view, I've got a button :

```
doctype 5
html(ng-app="lineApp")
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    p filename: #{filename}
    button(onclick="location.href='/app/#{filename}'") click me
```

The page display a paragraph with `filename: C:\users\username\my filename.txt`.
When I click on the button, the URL is something like `http://localhost:8080/app/C:usersusernamemy%20filename.txt`

So when I try to retrieve the parameter

```
exports.appli = function (req, res) {
    var filename = req.params.filename;
    //....
    });
};
```

with the server side call :

```
app.get('/app/:filename?', routes.appli);
```

I got an invalid filename. My question is then, how to pass a file path as a parameter in URL ?

Comment: As typed in the question, that would show up in `req.params` as `C:usersusernamemy filename.txt` which isn't a vaild windows path.  Is there a typo in the question?  Or is the path legitimately wrong?

Comment: Just edited the post to clarify. The variable #{filename} is a valid windows path, but when it's passed as a parameter, I loose the special characters. There is something to deal with escaping characters, but I don't know how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the slashes acting as escape characters.

The first time you pass the string to the client, any escaped slashes (ex: `c:\\users\\username\\my file.txt`) are converted to single slashes.

When you use `href.location`, the slashes act as escape characters *a second time*...which is why they drop out when you try to call the server using it.

You could:

1. Create two variables to pass to the jade template, one the filename as-is and the other an HTML encoded string
2. pass the variables to the jade template:

*For example, based upon your original jade:*

```
body
    p filename: #{filename}
    button(onclick="location.href='/app/#{encodedFilename}'") click me
```

Comment: what I was looking for was the "escape" javascript function :)

Comment: "escape" is depreciated and shouldn't be used. Look at encodeURI instead.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent